# find coordinates from a point and giving distancein plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, distance, euclidean-distance

Let's say I'm moving from the top of the peak with a giving distance of 1 nm before the peak (at left). How can I get the index or the coordinate of the arrival point?

data looks like this:

```
timeInS= [0.000000e+00, 1.000000e-10, 2.000000e-10, 3.000000e-10, 4.000000e-...]
force=[-0.0030, 20.3471, 41.1066, 8.4028, 60.1618 ...]
#distance is eucleadian distance
for i in range(len(force)-1):
    distance.append ( math.sqrt( ((ts[i]-f[i])**2)+((ts[i+1]-f[i+1])**2) ))
```

please see plot here: [force vs time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91vUO.png)

Comment: please provide the input coordinate sample and in which direction, we are moving e.g. x, y or at some angle.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not still clear, graph is between force and time, and you are asking in the terms of the distance(1nm).

Comment: yes, it is the euclidean distance between two points.

Comment: The units on the length of the orange line aren't nm.

Comment: You probably want the index of the max force.  Does this function [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html?highlight=argmax#numpy.argmax) fit the bill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let us suppose, we have point A= (t1, f1) at top and point C= (t2,f2), whose coordinates you know as shown in picture. Calculate the equation of the line

y = mx+c

[image]

Solve for fx and tx.